# Fermat's theorem for other numbers than whole numbers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Does anyone know what is the status of solutions of Fermat's equation
x^n+y^n=z^n
for x,y,z other numbers such as 1) integers, 2) algebraic numbers, specially Q[i] and Q(i), complex numbers?

In which numbers does the equation have solutions?

Comment: I can promise you that this is open. Fermat's Last Theorem was *barely* proven.

Comment: Well, some of these are not open - the algebraic numbers are an algebraically closed field, so any polynomial has the correct number of roots. Integers reduces to the case of natural numbers: if $n$ is even, just flip the signs on the negative integers, if $n$ is odd, just move the negatives integers to the other side. The other case of $\Bbb Q[i]=\Bbb Q(i)$ I do not immediately know the answer to, though.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some solutions for all the cases asked:

$2^3+(-2)^3=0^3$ (for integers)

$1^4+0^4=i^4$ (complex)

$(2^{\frac{1}{3}})^3+(5^{\frac{1}{3}})^3=(7^{\frac{1}{3}})^3$ (algebraic)

Comment: The Gaussian integers may be more interesting if $0$ is not allowed.

Comment: I am sorry I should have realised Q[i]=Q(i) and that complex and algebraic cases are not applicable.